# Flask integration with aws api gateway, lambda and dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I have a aws dyanmodb on my cloud account, which is queried by a lambda triggered by api gateway.
Now i want to have a simple flask application that sends requests via apigateway rather than postman. Can anyone help with the code. 
api gateway endpoint: https://3omrrlu81m.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default

This is a simple application for a larger application
please help.
Thanking You.

Comment: I not sure I understand. Did you mean you want to fetch data via a flask app, what have you done right now? Can your show your simple flask application code here?

Comment: Use requests or httpx something similar to make HTTP requests from code.

Comment: I have to develop a flask app that sits between aws api gateway and lambda. This is used to perform operations on DynamoDB. The request comes via api gateway, this requests should go to flask app then trigger the desired function in Lambda. I am planning to use flask and aws-wsgi can anybody help with flask code. Thank You